# Displaying single label in legend bar using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, legend

[image]

How do I display a single label in a legend bar using ArcMap?

Instead of showing min and Max .. just wanted to show max value!

Answer (score 2):

In ArcMap you need to change the labels in the symbology tab in de layer's properties menu in order to change them in the legend as well.

[image]